# Product of Jacobi Symbols over Reduced Residue System

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

#### Problem

For any odd composite number $m$ with at least $2$ distinct prime factors,
prove that $\displaystyle \prod_{\substack{1\leq i\leq m \\ \text{gcd}(i,m)=1}}\left(\frac{i}{m}\right) = 1$,
where $\left(\frac{.}{.}\right)$ is the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol), and $\text{gcd}(i,m)=1$ means that $i$ is coprime with $m$.

#### Attempts

I have already proved that for any odd prime number $p$,
$\displaystyle \prod_{\substack{1\leq i\leq p^n \\ \text{gcd}(i,p^n)=1}}\left(\frac{i}{p^n}\right) = 
\begin{cases}
-1 &\text{ if } p \text{ is of the form } 4k+3 \text{ and } n \text{ is odd,}\\
1 &\text{ if otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$
I was planning to factorize $m$ into prime powers, then somehow combine their Jacobi Symbols together or do induction.
However, things get complicated real quick because when $m$ changes, the numbers coprime to it changes greatly.
If $m$ is of the form $p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}$, it might still be manageable, but I don't know how to handle the general case.
Also, I found that its [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\phi(m)$ is even, which might be related.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For an odd $m > 1$ (composite or not), can you find for how many values $1 \leqslant i \leqslant m$ with $\gcd(i,m) = 1$ we have $\bigl(\frac{i}{m}\bigr) = -1$? What do you know about $\varphi(m)$ if $m$ has at least two distinct odd prime divisors?